# error: AWS session token not found when using rs_create_table

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

I was running the following code:

```
install.packages("aws.ec2metadata", repos = c(cloudyr = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat", getOption("repos")))

install.packages(c('devtools', 'httr', 'aws.s3', 'Rcpp', 'DBI'))

library(RPostgreSQL)
library(redshiftTools)
library(RPostgres)


devtools::install_github("sicarul/redshiftTools")

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

pconn_rsql <- dbConnect(drv,
                         host = "host",
                         port = port,
                         user = "user",
                         password = "password",
                         dbname = "dbname")

rs_create_table(df = mtcars,
            dbcon = conn,
            table_name = "table_name",
            bucket = "my-bucket",
            region = "region",
            access_key = "acess-key",
            secret_key = "secret-key",
            split_files = 4)

dbDisconnect(pconn_rsql)
```

It was running as a script perfectly until this morning when I updated the R packages. I checked the GitHub for any cues about it, but none worked. 
Has anyone already faced it and can shed a light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced a similar issue, one way you could do is revert back to `version 0.3.900` (this was the one that was working for me).

Alternatively you could fix the underlying `source` code. Download the github version and make some changes before you install.

**1. script `internal.R` function `s3ToRedshift` add `else if` condition for `session`**

```
  if (nchar(iam_role_arn) > 0) {
    credsStr = sprintf("iam_role '%s'", iam_role_arn)
  } else if (nchar(session) > 0){
    credsStr = sprintf("credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s;token=%s'", access_key, secret_key, session)
  } else {
    # creds string now includes a token in case it is needed.
    credsStr = sprintf("credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s'", access_key, secret_key)
  }
```

**2. script `replace.R` function `rs_replace_table` add `Sys.setenv`**

After `split_files = pmin(split_files, numRows)`, add following lines.

```
  # Set env variables for S3 upload
  Sys.setenv(
    'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'=region,
    'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'=access_key,
    'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'=secret_key,
    'AWS_IAM_ROLE_ARN'=iam_role_arn
  )
```

So it will look something like:

```
split_files = pmin(split_files, numRows)

  # Set env variables for S3 upload
  Sys.setenv(
    'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'=region,
    'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'=access_key,
    'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'=secret_key,
    'AWS_IAM_ROLE_ARN'=iam_role_arn
  )
  prefix = uploadToS3(df, bucket, split_files)
```

Install this and `rs_create_table` should now work, haven't tested the other functions though.

Comment: Hello, @Mka, which lib is meant to be downgraded to  0.3.9 ? I know it' asking a bit too much, but I'm newbie to R, but the downgrading would be smth like:
devtolls::install_version('Lib',version='0.3.9') ?

Comment: I think you can do it by `install_github` in `devtools`. Or have you tried updating the source code?

Comment: I updated the source code! 
It's now working. Thanks
:)